# Google Script on Google Form, Ref number issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to provide a ref number for the users who submitted the form. It is almost done except for one issue.

The ref number that users are getting is actually belongs to the next user. For example, when A submitted the form, and B submitted the form after A, A will get B's ref number in his confirmation page. B will instead be given the ref number of C (the next one who submitted).

Does anyone know why it is happening? Thanks!

```
function emailFormSubmission(e) {

        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();//the current form
        var dest_id = form.getDestinationId(); //the destination spreadsheet where form responses are stored
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dest_id);//open that spreadsheet
        var theFormSheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; //read the first sheet in that spreadsheet
        var row = theFormSheet.getLastRow(); //get the last row
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getTime(); // e.g. n = 1382489068127
        var range = theFormSheet.getRange(row, 5, 1, 1);
        range.setValue(n);
        form.setConfirmationMessage('Thanks for responding. Your Reference No. '+ n);
}
```

Comment: When & How is `emailFormSubmission` triggered ?

Comment: Please share a sanitised copy of your sheet.

Comment: Pro Tip: You can avoid generating a reference number by using the unique id of the form response instead...

Comment: @DimuDesigns Is it possible to get that unique ID from the SpreadSheet on form submit?

Comment: You're changing the confirmation message of the form, not for a form response. A form only has one confirmation message. This is what you're doing: A submits > update form confirmation message > B submits > update the form confirmation message > C submits > update the form confirmation. Have C submit and then check and you'll see that A will see C's ref code.

Comment: You probably want to email the submitter letting them know their ref code.